# Create alias of class with different properties (e.g. docs) but passing all cross `isinstance` checks

Tags: python, class, inheritance, isinstance

I have a class and want to create an alias for it. However, I want all instances of the alias class to pass the instance check with the original and alias class, and the same for all instances of the original class. Is that possible in python?

I tried the following (after some edits with comments) but it doesnt work.

```py
from abc import ABC

class ParentClass(ABC):
    """Abstract base class"""

class MetaClass(type):
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        return isinstance(instance, cls) or isinstance(instance, AliasClass)

class OGClass(ParentClass, metaclass=MetaClass):
    """OGClass docs"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.property1 = "property1"

class AliasClass(OGClass):
    """other doc"""

og_obj = OGClass()
ali_obj = AliasClass()

assert isinstance(og_obj, OGClass)    # True
assert isinstance(ali_obj, OGClass)   # True
assert isinstance(ali_obj, AliasClass)# True
assert isinstance(og_obj, AliasClass) # False, I want this to be True
```

Moreover it is important that both classes have separate doc strings, so I need

```py
assert OGClass.__doc__ == """OGClass docs""" # True
assert AliasClass.__doc__ == """other doc""" # True
```

Is that possible without doing something sketchy like setting `self.__class__ = AliasClass` in the `__init__` of `OGClass` (this works but I guess is not recommended?)

Comment: `__instancecheck__()` has to be defined on a metaclass, those methods are completely ineffective where you have them now.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? You could probably define `AliasClass` as an ABC without any actual abstract methods, then register `OGClass` as a virtual subclass of `AliasClass`, but I strongly suspect there is a better way to model whatever alias relationship you have in mind.

Comment: The background is that I have some class that is heavily relied upon in the codebase and different other repositories and I want to rename the class to something more sensible - yet without having to change the whole codebase and all its dependencies.

Comment: The overall goal is two have two classes with the same functionality but different names and different doc-strings, and in particular I want an object from either class to pass an instance check for either class.

Comment: I tried to create a metaclass and also the virtual subclassing, but couldnt get it to work. Would you mind typing out the above example with a metaclass or virtual subclass that passes provided assertions? For the metaclass example, the problem is that the actual situation is a bit more complicated and I am getting error `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`. I updated the original question to reflect that.